# How to get SYSTEM_USER of SQL Server in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure function to create SQL query and insert data in the database. One of the parameters I need to give for column `Added_by` should be `system_user`.

If I run `Select SYSTEM_USER;` I get username in SQL Server. But if I run the same command using Python in Azure function I get None.

How do I get `SYSTEM_USER`? And is `sql_user_name` same as `SYSTEM_USER`?

This is part of the code for reference:

```
sql_fetch_system_user = "SELECT SYSTEM_USER;"
system_user = exec_sql_query_no_params(sql_fetch_system_user, sql_server, database, sql_user_name, sql_password, sql_driver)
print("sql_user_name",system_user)


def exec_sql_query_no_params(query, sql_server, database, sql_user_name, sql_password, sql_driver):
    try:
        with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+sql_driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+sql_server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+sql_user_name+';PWD=' + sql_password) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                conn.autocommit = True
                cursor.execute(query)
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        logging.error(f"SQL query failed: {e}")
        raise
```

Comment: Some [explanation of the differences here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/853037/suser-name-vs-session-user-vs-others-i-need-de-log) - did you try any of the others, like `USER_NAME()`? Also, what's the point? You just want to sanity check that the connection worked with the user name you pasted right there into the connection string?

Comment: Is this an Azure SQL Database? You may want [`USER_NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: You aren'te fetching any result. You should call `cursor.fetchone`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for pointing that out. That's where the error was and I confirmed that sql_user_name is same as SYSTEM_USER

Comment: @heman123, can you post it as an answer as it will help the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and @Charlieface's observation are correct and below is the code which worked for me:

```
import os
import logging
import pyodbc
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    server1 = 'servername.database.windows.net'
    db1 = 'db1'
    username1 = 'user'
    pwd1 = 'Welcome$'
    constring = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};Server={server1};Database={db1};Uid={username1};Pwd={pwd1};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
    with pyodbc.connect(constring) as connec:
        with connec.cursor() as c1:
            c1.execute('SELECT SYSTEM_USER;')
            row = c1.fetchone()
    return func.HttpResponse(f"SQL Query Result: {row}", status_code=200)
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

And sql_user_name is similar as SYSTEM_USER