# Azure functions: "Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, azure-functions, odbc, pyodbc

I was able to upload an azure functions python project, it receives and returns requests, but for some reason i get the following error:

[image]

I tried using ODBC 18 and nothing.
I tried to use the `pyodbc.drivers()` trick but it shows me this:

[image]
It seems that Azure Functions has an empty list of drivers, and I'm starting to think it doesn't have any drivers installed.

Is there a way to install ODBC or other drivers?
Or there's another explanation about this issue?

Here's my code for creating the connection, I'm using PyODBC along with SQLAlchemy and Azure Functions (using Linux and python 3.11).

```py
url = URL.create(
            "mssql+pyodbc",
            username=os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
            password=os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
            host=os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
            port=1433,
            database=os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
            query={
                "driver": "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
                "TrustServerCertificate": "yes",
                "Encrypt": "yes",
            },
        )

    engine = create_engine(url, echo=echo, connect_args={"timeout": 40})
```

Thank you.

I tried changing to another driver version and I expected to work but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` works for me when deployed (but not 18)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`__init__.py`**

```
import os
import logging
import pyodbc
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request Rithwik.')
    server1 = 'servername.database.windows.net'
    db1 = 'rith'
    username1 = 'rithwik'
    pwd1 = 'password'
    constring = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};Server={server1};Database={db1};Uid={username1};Pwd={pwd1};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
    with pyodbc.connect(constring) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as c3:
            c3.execute('SELECT SYSTEM_USER;')
            row = c3.fetchone()
    print("User is ",row)
    return func.HttpResponse(f"SQL Query Result: {row}", status_code=200)
```

**`requirements.txt:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Try to integrate your code into mine and you will output as i have got. You can also refer my [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76942990/17623802)

Comment: you are running the function locally, the OP's issue is when the Az function is deployed

Comment: @bn_ln It even worked when I deployed then

Comment: Yes, me too actually!